# Gerrit behaviour to find change-id in last paragraph

Tags: gerrit, git-push, parsing-error

I am working on Gerrit. I know it has default behavior to find the change id in the footer message of commit message.Now my question is that can change this change this behavior.If yes pelase provide me idea about this. I want that gerrit parse all message to check change Id not only footer.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not currently possible, although it is a requested feature: https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=606